# Attaching Unity's integrated profiler to Mobile Devices

Tags: profiling, unity-game-engine

Has anyone successfully used the Unity profiler with a physical mobile device? (i.e. the Unity 3.4 IDE tool that provides real-time stats on Unity calls, not the iOS or Android internal profilers).  And if so, can you post the details about your setup and your experience?

I'm starting to get the feeling that people aren't using the profiler to test their games on real devices, given how little I can find in the Unity documentation and forums or on the web in general. In particular, [dreamora](http://forum.unity3d.com/members/2742-dreamora) is the only person I have heard of who has successfully attached the Unity profiler to a real device running a game (and then, only on iPhone not Android). It is also suspicious to me that the Android remote tool for Unity 3.4 which I downloaded form the marketplace requires a cable to connect to the Unity IDE and doesn't seem to have a wireless option; I see this as a red flag that wireless profiling by attaching the Unity profiler to an Android device may be impossible (please correct me someone if I'm wrong).

I would like to know your experiences (good or bad) with this tool, and assuming you have been able to profile a device, specifically I would like to know:

**1)** Did you connect to and Android or iOS?
**2)** What device and API version (i.e. Nexus S1 AndroidAPI=2.3.7 Kernel=2.6.35.14 running Cyanogen MOD 7.10)
**3)** What type of computer are you using (Windows or Mac, and OS)?
**4)** What is the nature of the connection you were able to make between your computer and the device?
**4.1)** Wired or wireless?
**4.2)** If wireless, ad-hoc from computer to device, tethering from device to computer, or both connected to the same WLAN router?
**4.3)** If wireless, what is the setup (DHCP, Static IP, ttl=4, etc?)
**5)** What are the Unity build settings (i.e. Development Build checked/unchecked, Autoconnect Profiler checked/unchecked, etc?)
**6)** What were the specific steps you took to connect to the device? (i.e. Build and run on device, then restart Unity twice, then offer up a prayer to the gods by sacrificing a Symbian phone, then connect via the Active Profiler pull-down, etc.)

Let's get to the bottom of this together, I will repost any information this community can provide me with in the Unity forums as well.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I am going to partially answer my own questions here:  By following these steps I was able to connect to and profile my Android Nexus running the Cyanogen Mod (7.1) using my MacBook pro (running 10.6.8 "Snow Leopard") on both Unity 3.4.1 and 3.4.2:

- Create a WiFi Hotspot using Internet sharing on your Mac. Use the "Share your connection from: Ethernet" and "To computers using AirPort (AirMac)" options. I did not password protect my network.
- Connect to this the WiFi network on your Android.
- Quit Unity.app (if you already launched it).
- Disable the Ethernet interface under System Preferences -> Network (select 'Off' from the Configure IPv4 pull-down menu)
- Launch Unity.app
- Enable Ethernet interface  under System Preferences -> Network (select 'Using DHCP' from the Configure IPv4 pull-down menu)

Now Your Android should be in the list of the Profiler window. Of course, you will need to launch a Unity application that was built with the 'Development Build' and 'Autoconnect Profiler' checkboxes selected under Build Settings (that's what I did at least).

Happy Hunting!

-Arun

Answer (score 0):

If the above don't work or you need to profile specifically on a Windows Phone, try the following...

1.) Make sure in Build Settings you set it to 'Development Build'.

2.) Connect your phone to your Wifi Network, then click on the wifi connection to see your phone's IP address

3.) Enter the phone's IP address in the profiler, and press the 'Record' button and the profiler will begin profiling on your phone.

4.) Run your game from Visual Studio, wait and you will see the profiling will begin.

***If you don't see your phone in the profiler, try this alternate method***

1.) Connect the phone to your PC

2.) Make sure in Build Settings you set it to 'Development Build'.

3.) Build the game to Visual Studio

4.) Run the game in 'Debug' mode from Visual Studio

5.) When the game is running on the device and is past any loading screens, click on the 'Active Profiler' dropdown in the profiler, and the device should be listed there